# Newton-Raphson Error

Tags: maximum-likelihood, contingency-tables, matrix-inverse, log-linear, hessian

According to Agresti(2013) pg 364-365, iterative methods such as Newton-Raphson methods, $
\begin{aligned}
\beta^\text{new} &= \beta^\text{old} + (X^{T}WX)^{-1}X^{T}(V)
\end{aligned}
$ help to estimate the MLE of log-linear models.

These are my $Y, X , n$ matrices. The first column in $X$ matrix represents the intercept 
($\beta_\text{0}$)

$$
Y=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
16 \\
30 \\
71 \\
102 \\
130 \\
133 \\
40 \\
4 \\
38 \\
119 \\
221 \\
259 \\
310 \\
226 \\
65 \\
\end{bmatrix} ;X= 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix};n=
\begin{bmatrix}
172675 \\
123065 \\
96216 \\
92051 \\
72159 \\
54722 \\
32185 \\
8328 \\
181343 \\
146207 \\
121374 \\
[111353 \\
83004 \\
55932 \\
29007 \\
7583 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

I am trying to fit a rate poisson model, $\log \lambda_i = \log n_i + \theta^T x$, for this data where the likelihood is $$\prod_{i=1}^N \dfrac{(n_ie^{\theta^Tx})^{y_i}}{y_i!}e^{-n_i e^{\theta^Tx}}$$

When i execute the Newton-Raphson procedure based on Agresti(2013) suggestion I am getting an error saying

```
Error in solve.default(t(X) %*% (V) %*% X) : 
  system is computationally singular: reciprocal condition number = 1.10707e-17
```

I am not sure what I am missing here for the inverse of the Hessian $H$ to throw that error. Need help. Please let me know if you need more details regarding my work.

Comment: Isn't it simply saying that in essence the Hessian is singular ?

Comment: @aginensky, agree but what is the solution I am not sure. Does it mean I should not use the newton Raphson approach ?

Comment: I'm not really an expert.  I'm sure the answer is yes, but...  You should google 'can I use Newton Raphson if the Hessian is singular".  Unless you data set is really large or you are unlucky, you can try something else like gradient descent or stochastic gradient descent.

Comment: @aginensky, I disagree. Gradient descent or Stochastic gradient descent might be relevant if my X are correlated. Here my X is not correlated. They are design matrices.

Comment: Your X matrix is clearly linearly dependent. Add all of the columns after the first. It's all 1's, just like the first column. Hence X'X is singular.

Comment: Newton, gradient descent etc. are numerical methods to solve equations.  I certainly didnt say they weren't relevant.

Comment: @Glen_b - perhaps you should add a sentence or two to your comment and post it as an answer, since it does answer the question and the fix is easy.

Comment: @jbowman yes; I was kind of hoping someone else would jump in but you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $X$ matrix is clearly linearly dependent. Add all of the columns after the first - it's all $1$'s, just like the first column. Hence $X^\top X$ is singular.

The usual solution is to omit a single factor level, typically either the first or the last. There are other approaches (which boil done to some form of linear constraint on the coefficients); which you would use will depend on your needs (though it's possible to translate between them, so it's not crucial which approach you use).

My suggestion is simply to omit the second column of your X-matrix; the level of that is incorporated into the constant term and the other coefficients will then represent differences (on the scale of the linear predictor) from that baseline.